# Cannot install or uninstall texlive

Tags: software-installation, uninstall, texlive

so after I updated from 16.10 to 17.04 I've been having nothing but problems. My biggest is that texlive had problems and now I can't compile any Latex files. So I tried removing before reinstalling. Thought it had worked. Then I tried to reinstall with `sudo apt-get install texlive` and got

```
Selecting previously unselected package fonts-texgyre.
(Reading database ... 236984 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-fonts-texgyre_20160520-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking fonts-texgyre (20160520-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfile-homedir-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libfile-homedir-perl_1.00-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libfile-homedir-perl (1.00-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../02-texlive-generic-recommended_2016.20170123-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking texlive-generic-recommended (2016.20170123-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-latex-recommended.
Preparing to unpack .../03-texlive-latex-recommended_2016.20170123-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking texlive-latex-recommended (2016.20170123-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-pictures.
Preparing to unpack .../04-texlive-pictures_2016.20170123-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking texlive-pictures (2016.20170123-5) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-0MB8K8/04-texlive-pictures_2016.20170123-5_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create new file '/var/lib/dpkg/info/texlive-pictures.list-new': Operation not permitted
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-pstricks.
Preparing to unpack .../05-texlive-pstricks_2016.20170123-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking texlive-pstricks (2016.20170123-5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../06-prosper_1.00.4+cvs.2007.05.01-4.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking prosper (1.00.4+cvs.2007.05.01-4.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ps2eps.
Preparing to unpack .../07-ps2eps_1.68+binaryfree-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ps2eps (1.68+binaryfree-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package tex-gyre.
Preparing to unpack .../08-tex-gyre_20160520-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking tex-gyre (20160520-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-fonts-recommended.
Preparing to unpack .../09-texlive-fonts-recommended_2016.20170123-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking texlive-fonts-recommended (2016.20170123-5) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-0MB8K8/09-texlive-fonts-recommended_2016.20170123-5_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/adobe/times/ptmro8c.vf.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
Selecting previously unselected package texlive.
Preparing to unpack .../10-texlive_2016.20170123-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking texlive (2016.20170123-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-extra-utils.
Preparing to unpack .../11-texlive-extra-utils_2016.20170123-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking texlive-extra-utils (2016.20170123-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-font-utils.
Preparing to unpack .../12-texlive-font-utils_2016.20170123-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking texlive-font-utils (2016.20170123-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-fonts-recommended-doc.
Preparing to unpack .../13-texlive-fonts-recommended-doc_2016.20170123-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking texlive-fonts-recommended-doc (2016.20170123-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-latex-recommended-doc.
Preparing to unpack .../14-texlive-latex-recommended-doc_2016.20170123-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking texlive-latex-recommended-doc (2016.20170123-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-pictures-doc.
Preparing to unpack .../15-texlive-pictures-doc_2016.20170123-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking texlive-pictures-doc (2016.20170123-5) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-0MB8K8/15-texlive-pictures-doc_2016.20170123-5_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create new file '/var/lib/dpkg/info/texlive-pictures-doc.list-new': Operation not permitted
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-pstricks-doc.
Preparing to unpack .../16-texlive-pstricks-doc_2016.20170123-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking texlive-pstricks-doc (2016.20170123-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package tipa.
Preparing to unpack .../17-tipa_2%3a1.3-20_all.deb ...
Unpacking tipa (2:1.3-20) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-0MB8K8/04-texlive-pictures_2016.20170123-5_all.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-0MB8K8/09-texlive-fonts-recommended_2016.20170123-5_all.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-0MB8K8/15-texlive-pictures-doc_2016.20170123-5_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then I tried `apt install -f` which resulted in

```
(Reading database ... 243034 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../texlive-fonts-recommended_2016.20170123-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking texlive-fonts-recommended (2016.20170123-5) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-fonts-recommended_2016.20170123-5_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/urw35vf/helvetic/uhvb8t.tfm.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-fonts-recommended_2016.20170123-5_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

In a different post I read that I have to force it to overwrite, so I did with `sudo dpkg -i --force all /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-fonts-recommended_2016.20170123-5_all.deb`. It went without errors, but showed that some packages were not fully installed, so I asked for those with `dkpg -C`. There it said some were not configured (did with `dpkg --configure -a`), some were triggered but trigger processing had not been done (did with `dpkg --configure --pending`). Then also

```
The following packages are missing the md5sums control file in the
database, they need to be reinstalled:
 texlive-pictures     TeX Live: Graphics, pictures, diagrams
 texlive-pictures-doc TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-pictures
```

When configuring, one package said it could not be configured, because another had not been configured yet. I tried to configure this one afterwards, but then I got dependency problems:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-pstricks:
 texlive-pstricks depends on texlive-pictures (>= 2016.20170123-2); however:
  Package texlive-pictures is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-pstricks (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

I did `sudo apt-get install texlive-pictures` and it showed

```
Reading state information... Done
texlive-pictures is already the newest version (2016.20170123-5).
texlive-pictures set to manually installed.
```

I really don't understand and am at loss as to what to do now.

Here's what came out of `apt-get purge texlive`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'texlive' is not installed, so not removed
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 7 not to upgrade.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/108 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-pstricks:
 texlive-pstricks depends on texlive-pictures (>= 2016.20170123-2); however:
  Package texlive-pictures is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-pstricks (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                            No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                        dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of prosper:
 prosper depends on texlive-pstricks; however:
  Package texlive-pstricks is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package prosper (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 texlive-pstricks
 prosper
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't install probably, how about purging and reinstall? Use

```
apt-get purge texlive
```

for that. And then just try installing

Edit: To conclude how the problem was solved:
used

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

To install aptitude package manager(Maybe not necessary)

```
sudo aptitude install texlive_
```

to purge texlive

```
sudo aptitude -f install texlive
```

to install texlive that should install texlive, now followed an error when compiling that some .sty are missing, it was solved by

```
sudo aptitude -f reinstall texlive-pictures
sudo aptitude -f install texlive-latex-extra
```

That should solve all issues

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59227/discussion-on-answer-by-addb-cannot-install-or-uninstall-texlive).